# Modelling odd-even distinction of an integer with neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

Will it be possible to model the problem of odd-even distinction of an integer (not binary string representation) using neural networks?

Comment: say whaaaaat? anyways nn's are modeled after our brain..can we say a no. is even just by seeing it? no..hence nn cant perform it

Comment: Your reasoning just doesn't convince me. I just am trying to deduce the reasons on why this problem can(t) be modelled with neural nets. In the lines of, say the virtue of the modulo function being non continuous etc.

Comment: Because its random for one..NN's are for pattern recognition it NN certainly doesn't work on maths like that..it models a function by looking at the pattern not because it is continuous or something else

Comment: Welcome to AI!   Can you post some links referencing the problem.  I found this [Odd-even distinction](http://www.psych.mcgill.ca/perpg/fac/shultz/StudentProjects/Odd-evenDistinction.htm) but there's no real detail regarding why it's so difficult.

Comment: @DukeZhou Actually I'm not sure on whether it is a difficult problem in the first place. I couldn't really come up with a solution nor references where it is discussed. Hence the question